# Fastest way to update datatable

Tags: c#, performance, datatable

Assume we have a DataTable with 100 columns and 100 rows.
We have a dictionary of values like this that contains 100 members:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = GetValues();
```

In above dictionary key is index of the Datatable and value of dictionary is target value that we want to update in Datatable.

What's the fastest way to update the Datatable? I use this way but it's slow :

```
      foreach (var pair    in dictionary)
        {

            timeTable.Rows[pair.Key].SetField(columnIndex, pair.Value);
        }
```

Assuming we have to update all rows of 40 columns, it doesn't have good performance. I was thinking that Datatable is like a Matrix and it shouldn't take time at all when you want to update a cell on Matrix while you have indexes of the row and the column.

Comment: What do you mean by "slow" ? What are the measures ? Also is it the "GetValues()" method that takes time, or th foreach itself only ?

Comment: 100x100 is tiny in terms of data.

Answer (score 1):

DataTable is a very expensive structure that dos a lot behind the scenes (particularly because they are designed to handle anything).

If performance is critical consider:

- Creating your own structure, such as a class encapsulating an array of strings arrays (e.g. a strings matrix, on which access will be very fast)
- Udating your table in parallel (since you are never accessing the same row), knowing that DataTable is NOT thread safe for writing operations.

e.g.

```
// Probably not thread safe, after the MSDN documentation
Parallel.ForEach(Dictionary, pair =>
    {
      timeTable.Rows[pair.Key].SetField(columnIndex, pair.Value);
    });
```

EDIT: This will not work in the general case (write operations even on distinct rows might affect global state of the DataTable, so I suggest that you go with your own structure if performance is critical, and if you don't need specific features of the DataTable)

Comment: Thank you Karim, would you please put a sample regarding updating in parallel ?

Comment: That's right, it throws exception, actually since I have binded the Datatable to DataGrid I can't use any other structure, well I am aware of possibilty of binding list of object to DataGrid, but in my scenario I user may generate extra columns run time that's why I use DataTable